# Could not find overload for -, although all arguments are double

Tags: swift

I try to find value of polynomial from pr. Here is my code:

```
let x = Double(pr)
let x2 : Double = pow(x, 2.0)
let x3 : Double = pow(x, 3.0)
let x4 : Double = pow(x, 4.0)
let r = CGFloat( 4.8 * x4 - 10.4 * x3 + 5.7 * x2 + 1.05 * x + 0.95 )
let g = CGFloat( 4.8 * x4 - 8.8 * x3  + 3.3 * x2 + 1.65 * x + 0.0 )
let b = CGFloat(0.0)
let color = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
return color.CGColor
```

There is not so much to explain, it just throws complier’s error: “Could not find overload for ‘-‘ that accepts supplied arguments. Also I tried to use `powf(x, 2)` with float types everywhere. `pr` is function `CGFloat` type parameter. Here is screenshot: [image: screenshot].

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a compiler bug (and it might be worth a bug report at Apple).
The compiler messages in the Report navigator show

```
note: expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
let g = CGFloat( 4.8 * x4 - 8.8 * x3  + 3.3 * x2 + 1.65 * x + 0.0 )
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As a workaround, you can assign the expression to a temporary variable first:

```
let tmp = 4.8 * x4 - 10.4 * x3 + 5.7 * x2 + 1.05 * x + 0.95
let r = CGFloat( tmp )
```

*Remark:* A more efficient method to evaluate a polynomial at a given point
is [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method):

```
let tmp = (((4.8 * x - 10.4) * x + 5.7) * x + 1.05) * x + 0.95
```

where you don't have to compute the various powers of `x`.

Comment: Build successful! Thanks:)

Comment: Extremely interesting question and answer.